# Inputting file name through main function argument (args[0])

Tags: java, netbeans

EDIT: to run my code i am using "java filename.java input1.txt" is this correct?

I am creating a program where i have to tokenize a string into separate words and that string is in a text file. I have to specify the text file name in the terminal through command line arguments (args[0], etc). I am able to scan and print the content of the text file if i specify through paths but when i try to do it using args[0] it doesn't seem to work. I am using net beans. I will attach my section of code here:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {   
    try {
        File f = new File(args[0]);   
        //using this commented out section using paths works File f = new 
        //File("NetBeansProjects/SentenceUtils/src/input1.txt");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(f));

        while(input.hasNext()) {
            String s = input.next();
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    } catch(FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
        System.out.println("File not found");
    }

    SentenceUtils s = new SentenceUtils();
}
```

Comment: How do you run your program?

Comment: _"it doesn't seem to work"_ ... in what way? No ouput? Exception? ... Please read [ask] and improve the question. Have you verified args[0] actually contains your path?

Comment: It doesn't work as in when i run it through terminal it just always gives me the "File not found" error.

Comment: also, i run it through netbeans and specify the command line argument in netbeans by doing project -> properties -> run and putting "input1.txt" in the line

Comment: input1.txt is in the same path as my program btw

Comment: Please add to your question the full command you write in your terminal to run the program.

Comment: i also just tried running it through terminal and did "java filename.java input1.txt " and still got the "file not found". BTW thank you guys for replies, means lot :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
java filename.java input1.txt
```

is not correct for running a java program, you need to compile the `*.java` file to get a `*.class` file which you can then run like:

```
java filename input1.txt
```

assuming your class is in the default package and you are running the command in the output directory of your compile command, or using the fully qualified class name of the class, i.e. including the package name. For example if your class is in the package `foo/bar/baz` (sub folders in your source folder) and has the package declaration `package foo.bar.baz;`, then you need to specify your class like this:

```
java [-cp  your-classpath] foo.bar.baz.filename input1.txt
```

for `input1.txt` to be found it has to be in the same directory where you run the command.

`your-classpath` is a list of directories separated by a system dependent delimiter (`;` for windows, `:` for linux, ...) or archives which the `java` command uses to look up the class to run specified and its dependencies.

`NetBeansProjects/SentenceUtils/src/input1.txt` is a relative path.

```
File f = new File("NetBeansProjects/SentenceUtils/src/input1.txt");
```

if this works then it means that the current working directory (i.e. the directory from which all relative paths are calculated) is the the rectory named `NetBeansProjects`.

You get `FileNotFoundException` because your file is expected to be in

```
NetBeansProjects/input1.txt
```

To find out which is the current working directory for your running program you can add the following statement:

```
System.out.println(new File("").getAbsolutePath());
```

Place `input.txt` in that directory and it will be found.

Alternatively you can pass the absolute path of your input file. an absolute path is a path that can be used to locate your file from whatever location your program is running from on your local filesystem. For example:

```
    java -cp <your-classpath> <fully-qualified-name-of-class> /home/john/myfiles/myprogects/...../input1.txt
```

To sum up, what you need to know/do is the following:

- the location of your program class and its package (filename)
- the location of your input file (input.txt)
- pass the correct argument accordingly

Comment: Perfect, thank you, i will look into this tomorrow morning. Been going all night and I'm fried haha. thanks :)

Comment: No, you don't pass a .class file to the java command. You pass the fully qualified name of a class: java com.mycompany.myproject.Main. Java then looks for this class in the classpath.

Comment: @JBNizet I am ashamed :(